# Trying to instantiate a wx.HeaderCtrl and getting an unfamiliar error

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a wx.HeaderCtrl object and I'm getting an error that I haven't been able to find on google. This is the code:

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title="Configuration")
        self.frame.Show()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(1600, 800))
        self.configpanel = MyPanel(self)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        foo = MyHeaderCtrl(self)
        foo.Create(self)

class MyHeaderCtrl(wx.HeaderCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

My problem is in the My Panel class, where I try to instantiate the HeaderCtrl foo, and then create it. No matter how I organize those, or what kind of window or panel I set as the parent of Create I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/_Code/Projects/Personal/BigOlTimeline/Python/test.py", line
>   32, in 
>       app = MyApp()
>
> File "C:/_Code/Projects/Personal/BigOlTimeline/Python/test.py", line
>   7, in **init**
>       self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title="Configuration")
>
> File "C:/_Code/Projects/Personal/BigOlTimeline/Python/test.py", line
>   14, in **init**
>       self.configpanel = MyPanel(self)
>
> File "C:/_Code/Projects/Personal/BigOlTimeline/Python/test.py", line
>   22, in **init**
>       foo = MyHeaderCtrl(self).Create(wx.Window())
>
> wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion ""!m_hWnd"" failed at
>   ....\src\msw\window.cpp(3971) in wxWindow::MSWCreate(): window can't
>   be recreated
>
> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

This is my first introduction to implementing abstract classes, and having to use a separate Create() instead of just the **init**, so I'm sure it's something simple but I had a lot of trouble finding anything similar online.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this a complete code you showed? It looks like you alrerady created the control and trying to create the same instance of the object again...

Comment: Yes that's a working program that recreates the error. I would agree with you accept the documentation for the function says I have to run Create after I've instantiated it. "__init__ (self)

Default constructor not creating the underlying window.

You must use Create after creating the object using this constructor."

Comment: it is possible wxPython does not support 2 way window creation.

Comment: This was pulled from the wxpython documentation, but say it didn't, how would I make this work?

Comment: just look at wxpython demo and samples

Comment: And thats the problem, I can't find an example of how to use HeaderCtrl or for that matter any abstract classes that require a .Create()

Comment: It never says you are supposed to call Create. Remove Create call and you won't get the error. The docs OTOH say:  it can’t be used directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wxWidgets, you can't call `Create()` if you have already created a window using its non-default constructor. In your code, you already create the window by calling its `__init__` in your own version, so you must not call `Create()` later -- just remove this line to fix the problem.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for, I was sure I was just misunderstanding the functionality. Thank you so much.